# How to change the group order in a TListGroups?

Tags: listview, delphi, delphi-2009

I have a `TListView` in `vsReport` style with groups visible. The groups are shown in the order in which they were created. But I want to make two buttons (up and down) and move the selected group on another position (at runtime). Is it possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by changing the `Index` property of the group item. The following code demonstrates the usage:

```
procedure TForm1.btnMoveUpClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  itm: TListItem;
  i: Integer;
begin
  itm := ListView1.Selected;
  if Assigned(itm) then
    for i := 0 to ListView1.Groups.Count - 1 do
      if ListView1.Groups[i].GroupID = itm.GroupID then
      begin
        if ListView1.Groups[i].Index > 0 then
          ListView1.Groups[i].Index := ListView1.Groups[i].Index - 1;
        break;
      end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnMoveDownClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  itm: TListItem;
  i: Integer;
begin
  itm := ListView1.Selected;
  if Assigned(itm) then
    for i := 0 to ListView1.Groups.Count - 1 do
      if ListView1.Groups[i].GroupID = itm.GroupID then
      begin
        if ListView1.Groups[i].Index < ListView1.Groups.Count - 1 then
          ListView1.Groups[i].Index := ListView1.Groups[i].Index + 1;
        break;
      end;
end;
```

*Footnote:* Of course, this can (should) be refactored like this:

```
function GetGroupFromGroupID(AListView: TListView; AGroupID: integer): TListGroup;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to AListView.Groups.Count - 1 do
    if AListView.Groups[i].GroupID = AGroupID then
      Exit(AListView.Groups[i]);
  result := nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnMoveUpClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  itm: TListItem;
  grp: TListGroup;
begin
  itm := ListView1.Selected;
  if Assigned(itm) then
  begin
    grp := GetGroupFromGroupID(ListView1, itm.GroupID);
    if Assigned(grp) and (grp.Index > 0) then
      grp.Index := grp.Index - 1;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnMoveDownClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  itm: TListItem;
  grp: TListGroup;
begin
  itm := ListView1.Selected;
  if Assigned(itm) then
  begin
    grp := GetGroupFromGroupID(ListView1, itm.GroupID);
    if Assigned(grp) and (grp.Index < ListView1.Groups.Count - 1) then
      grp.Index := grp.Index + 1;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Of course, you probably would like to refactor this by extracting a `GetGroupFromGroupID` function.

Comment: But where can I find that function ?

Comment: By 'refactoring by extracting', I mean you write the function yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. By changing the group item's [**Index**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TCollectionItem.Index).

Comment: It's worth adding that MS made API for this purpose (`LVM_MOVEGROUP` message, or `ListView_MoveGroup` macro). But they did not implement them.

Comment: It's ok. It works fine changing the Index. Thanks :)